# Sequelize included Model result keys are strings

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Forgive my limited knowledge im about a week into using Sequelize,

```
 Models.PlannerModel.Builds.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        ProposedDelivery: { [Op.gt]: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") },
        description: { [Op.ne]: null },
        description: { [Op.ne]: " " },
        description: { [Op.not]: null },
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Models.PlannerModel.Unit,
          required: true
        },
      ],
```

the result from the above is as you would expect except all the keys for the fields in the includes are as strings so referencing them in my Pug template/class has to be done with brackets

overall not the end of the world just wondering if im doing something wrong ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `raw` to get nested model objects and also to get plain objects use `get({ plain: true})` for each returned model instance:

```js
 const builds = await Models.PlannerModel.Builds.findAll({
      where: {
        ProposedDelivery: { [Op.gt]: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") },
        [Op.and]: [{
          description: { [Op.ne]: null },
        }, {
          description: { [Op.ne]: " " },
        }, {
          description: { [Op.not]: null },
        }
        ]
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Models.PlannerModel.Unit,
          required: true
        },
      ]
 })
 const plainBuilds = builds.map(x => x.get({ plain: true }))
```

Please pay attention that I changed conditions with `description`. In your version of conditions only the last one will work because JS saves only the last key if there are several same keys in the same object.